# Error Installing ProPowerTools.vsix extension in Visual Studio Web Developer 2012

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010

It is throwing me an error

**Visual Studio Extension Installer**

**This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.**

How to Install it in Web Developer 2010 Express

Comment: i can install NuGet Package manager and MVVM Editor Silverlight Templates , why not this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install extensions on Express, only the full version of visual stuido (with a few exceptions).

There is more detail here on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755873/productivity-power-tools-on-vs-2010-express-for-windows-phone)